# Page not found error happens-Can <str:id> be used?

Tags: django

Page not found error happens-Can  be used?

I wrote in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('^data/<str:id>', views.data, name='data'),
]

in views.py
def data(id):
    ・
    ・
    ・
    return None
```

For example, when I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/AD04958 ,
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/AD04958

error happens.

I think I can write this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/AD04958 into '^data/' in urls.py,so I really cannot understand why this error happens. id is not  save in Database,does it cause this error?
What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: @marin I read your documentation,but i cannot find how I should fix this.If you know something,please help me

Comment: @flaskbeginner note that Django 1.8 is end of life, and does not receive security updates anymore. Upgrade to Django 2.0 or 1.11 LTS if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Django<=1.11.x**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^data/(?P<id>[\w.-]+)/$', views.data, name='data'),
]
```

For **Django>=2**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('^data/<str:id>', views.data, name='data'),
]
```